Getting lost on a Circular Track
Since it is such a nice day, you decide to have a nice long walk on a very large circular road nearby. The radius of that circle is known to you, but it is so large that you cannot tell the inside from the outside simply from looking. After spending a good while getting lost, you would eventually like to go home. But where was the exit? You remember that you can leave this track only at a single point. Moreover, this point is very easy to miss - simply walking by will not do, you will need to stop very close to it for a moment to notice.
Now, the trouble is that you happen to have an extremely bad sense of direction. Even after stopping for just a second, you immediately forget from which direction you just came! As such, simply walking very small steps in the same direction is not an option for you. So, how do you get out?
Can you figure out a strategy to find the exit eventually?
(Note: This is intended to be a mathematical puzzle, not a lateral-thinking one. The precise interpretations of the casual terms should be:

The track is a perfect (Euclidean) circle of known radius.
You are a point somewhere on that circle, but the exact location is unknown to you.
The exit is a small segment on the circle. You don't know how small, so that your strategy should work for every possible size.
At every point in time you may move any (perfectly precise) distance in a single direction on the track, but you cannot tell if your movement will be clockwise or counterclockwise.
You win if and only if some of your movement results in you stopping in the exit segment.

Also, your strategy should guarantee that you eventually get out in every possible case - simply working a lot of the time (in some probabilistic sense, say) would not be enough.)
And, if this was too easy for you, here is a small bonus question:

 Suppose that the exit is also just a single point (instead of a segment). Can you determine the exact starting locations from which you have a shot at escaping reliably? (This also involves showing that the other points cannot be won by any strategy, not just the one you came up with.)

I hope you enjoy this little puzzle, have fun! :)

This problem is too hard! I'd almost surely have to walk around randomly and hope for the best.

I'm interpreting the last paragraph to mean that the strategy must work for all cases, against adversarially chosen directions? Merely working with probability 1 (assuming independently sampled directions) is insufficient, right? I initially interpreted that paragraph in a different way, and spent some time thinking up a solution that does boil down to just walking very small steps in the same direction.

@shapewarriort Yes, the strategy should work for all cases, i.e. from all locations and for every sequence of chosen directions (in particular, for adversarially chosen ones but there is no need to impose intent). For instance, using some basic facts about rot13(enaqbz jnyxf), it is not hard to see that rot13(jnyxvat gur fnzr (veengvbany) yratgu ng rirel ghea) let's you get out with probability 1 from every location, but this is not enough here :)

I think that choosing a sequence of positive real numbers that converges to $0$ sufficiently slowly would work for any radius at the same time.

Oh, ok, I thought the directions were chosen randomly. My strategy doesn’t work if it is an opponent that chooses our directions to make us lose, because of what we know of alternating series.

@Plop Ah, I see you changed your mind, I was about to respond already :) (Note though, that the directions are neither chosen at random nor by an adversarial opponent. You simply need to find a strategy to deal with all possible choices of directions here.)

Ok, except that in my opinion, « adversarial opponent » or « all possible choices » are equivalent ways to say the same thing :D

@Plop Hm ... To me, the first phrasing suggests that the choices would then need to conform to some sort of strategy, which is a restriction, I don't want to make. (In this situation, this does not matter for the outcome, but there certainly exist (under ZFC) combinatorial games like this where neither player has a winning strategy, i.e. where you may defeat any opponent following a specific strategy, yet are not able to defeat every possible counterplay.) This is perhaps overly pedantic here, so feel free to disagree :)

Ooooooh, ok, ok, I agree with you now :)

Without wishing to reveal the spoilers, I'd like to know how it's possible to 'go half-way round the circle' when it's given that you have such a bad sense of direction that even after stopping for just a second, you immediately forget from which direction you just came…

@RobbieGoodwin You simply walk without stopping until you have walked a distance of half the circumference. Once you stop, you no longer know which path took you there, but the result will be the same either way. :)

Please explain how it could be possible to know you had walked half the distance under the conditions given.

@RobbieGoodwin I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for here. Not to state the obvious, but the puzzle (clearly!) takes place in a thoroughly unrealistic scenario. Your ability to walk perfectly precise distances is just as much a conceit as the assumption that you are a single point on a perfect circle. For both, there is no real explanation how it is possible, since it so clearly is not! If you wish, you may pretend that your character carries some magic step counter or something. But really, you can only do it, because the puzzle explicitly says so

@TimSeifert I'm simply asking you to explain how, given the stated constraints, you could know you had walked half the circumference?
Of course if you could do that, the result would be the same either way but how could you do it?
How could you know you'd walked half - or any portion - of the circumference without knowing the circumference itself and its relationship to both your start and end points… and how would that not render the OQ pointless?

@RobbieGoodwin Ah, I see. The circumference is known to you.

@TimSeifert How could anyone think that? I'm still and only asking you to explain how you could know you had walked half the circumference. Why not try, please?

I guess I don't understand your question then. It is stated (twice) in the post, that the radius of the circle (therefore also its circumference) is known to you and that you may walk any perfectly precise distance at a time. What else is there to explain?

@RobbieGoodwin It is a condition of the problem that we know both the size of the track and the exact distance walked - the premises don't really need any justification. If the track has length X, walk a distance X/2 in either direction to go halfway around it. In practice, suppose you have a measuring wheel and amnesia that only strikes when you stop moving.

Nuclear Hoagie not for the first time, does anyone else think you can have it both ways?
The radius might be known, but if it's so large you can't tell in- from outside, how could it matter?
Leaving the track at any point, walking by or stopping to notice. could be 'reasonable' how?
Your idea of what might follow from your own or anyone else's bad sense of direction is up to you and please, how could there be more to that?

Again sorry, and if 'we' know both the size of the track and the exact distance walked, what might the question hope to achieve/ answer/ resolve…
Please, what am I missing?

Puzzles that require an solution that takes an infinite time to solve. Hmm. How is any solution better than walk/stop/walk/stop randomly?

No precise interpretation of any terms could ever include 'You are a point…'
How could that not be obvious?

@JiminyCricket. It doesn't take an infinite time though. For any possible starting scenario, the accepted answer will take you out in finitely many steps (even boundedly many steps, with a finite bound that you can easily extract from the answer beforehand). It is just that different starting positions may take different lengths of time to solve, so that the strategy cannot be finite overall. But in every scenario you find yourself in, you will definitely get out in finitely many steps (which cannot be guaranteed for choosing randomly)

OK, seems like I should brush-up on infinities again. It's been a few decades. @TimSeifert

For the non-zero segment size:

 The following recursive "binary search"-ish method works for arbitrarily small exit size. (Checking for the exit after every move):

 Search 1:
 - Go half-way round the circle.
 (This checks two points equally spaced around the circle.)

 Search 2:
 - Do search 1.
 - Go 1/4 round (doesn't matter which way).
 - Repeat search 1.
 (This checks four points equally spaced around the circle.)

 Search 3:
 - Do search 2.
 - Go 1/8 round (still doesn't matter which way).
 - Repeat search 2.
 (This checks eight points equally spaced around the circle.)

 Search 4:
 - Do search 3.
 - Go 1/16 round.
 - Repeat search 3.
 (This checks sixteen points equally spaced around the circle.)

 ...

 Search N:
 - Do search N-1.
 - Go 1/(2^N) round the circle.
 - Repeat search N-1
 (Checks 2^N points equally spaced around the circle.)

 ...

For the zero segment size case:

 The above strategy will find the exit only if the distance from the starting point around the circle is a rational fraction with a power-of-2 denominator.
 Which works out to approximately 0% of the time for a uniformly distributed exit.
 I can't see any way of improving this number.


This was fast, good work! (This is essentially the intended strategy as well.) Good luck on that remaining bonus part, if you're interested :)

Beautifully solved. One nitpick: Search 1 needs a step to search where you start in case you're already there.

For the single-point exit, you can't do better than @fljx's answer.

To simplify the notations, let's use a circle of circumference one, suppose the exit is at 0, and you don't know where you are. Note that for this problem, the location x+1 is the same as the location x (there are multiple number for each location). Let $\mathbb{B}$ (for binary fractions) be the set of fraction of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$. If you are on $\mathbb{B}$, you can escape using the strategy described in @fljx's answer.


On the other hand, if you are not in $\mathbb{B}$, then you can't guarantee to go to $\mathbb{B}$: Let's say you are at location $x$ and choose to walk distance $d$, then you want $x+d = y_1$ and $x-d = y_2$ with $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $\mathbb{B}$, but then $x = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}$ is in $\mathbb{B}$, contradiction. So you can't guarantee to reach 0 if you start outside of $\mathbb{B}$, and $\mathbb{B}$ is exactly the set of positions where you can guarantee a win.

Watch out, because:

If at any point you move a distance that is not in $\mathbb{B}$, at least one of the two directions will take you out of $\mathbb{B}$ and you can't guarantee a win anymore.


Exactly right, nicely done :)

It might take awhile, but we can get out.

Suppose the circle has circumference $1$. The strategy is to pick any irrational number $X$, say $\sqrt{2}$, and walk in increasing binary multiples of that number. From your starting point, walk distances $X$, $2X$, $4X$, $8X$, and so on. This martingale strategy ensure we can't fall into a loop of moving backwards to already-visited points, and the irrationality of $X$ ensures that we won't revisit points when moving forward completely around the rational-length track, either. We can continue our strategy as long as we like and continue to visit new points on the circle, ensuring that we will eventually find the exit.


As pointed out in the comments, visiting an infinite number of unique points doesn't alone prove we find the exit, for example, if we "only" check the infinite points on one contiguous semicircle. But if our strategy did that, it would imply that the strategy would have worked on a smaller circle, and that we'd have succeeded if we had just doubled the step size to start. Our premise, however, is that the choice of our irrational step size doesn't depend at all on the size of the track.


Hm, while you certainly will not repeat any position with this strategy, I don't find it so clear that your sequence of positions has to be dense in the circle. In fact, I don't even see why you couldn't just stay in the same half of the circle following this strategy. Can you elaborate on that?

@TimSeifert Yes, I realized some gaps in the logic after I posted this. Visiting an infinite number of unique points itself doesn't guarantee those points cover all arbitrarily small segments of the circle. I think it works out since we eventually start doing full loops and the irrational step size modulo the number of loops is itself irrational, and the binary multiples just keep pushing that "phase" further and further around the circle, but not quite sure how to prove it.

I think you can build a counterexample along these lines: Regard the circle as $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$ and pick a number whose binary representation contains increasingly vast stretches of 0's interupted by single 1's (clearly irrational, in particular). Multiplying by $2^n$ then has the effect of shifting the binary representation forward $n$ steps. Thus, whenever you have just "pushed past" another 1 and await a long stretch of 0's, you may could walk in the same direction for all of the 0's and in the different one for the following 1 ...

... If that stretch was long enough, this will result in taking steps in a single direction up to almost a half circle, then walking back to almost the start, so there should be almost no net movement. I haven't worked it out exactly, but it seems that making these stretches long enough should then let you bound the sum of all the errors to (say) 1/6. As a consequence, your movement will stay entirely within 2/3 of the circle.

(Now, choosing some specific value instead may still give rise to a valid strategy, but this shows that it will not work for every irrational number.)

@TimSeifert Hm, interesting. Although I suppose staying in some limited segment would require a specific sequence of moves. Maybe this works almost surely with 100% probability in the long term, yet still isn't guaranteed to work as the problem requires?

Maybe it does, I don't know! I haven't thought about it, but perhaps you can also find some number that leads to some strictly positive chance of failure. (I would be surprised it you can guarantee failure, but wouldn't even rule that out yet)

I don't think this works if you pick $X = \sum \frac{1}{2^{k!}}$ for exemple. On the other hand, you can follow @fljx's strategy with some small decreasing error and win, and maybe you can encode that in a carefuly crafted X, but it seems artificial.

If you rely on luck, playing random numbers is also a solid strategy, and you have a chaotic system generating your numbers so it should work! I think almost all strategies have a 100% winning chance in the long run. Only the ones very close to playing $\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $n$ fixed will have a positive chance of losing I think.

This seems to depend on the length of the track being rational, but the puzzle does not promise that. But I guess you could fix that by choosing X more carefully, in light of the known radius and (therefore) circumference of the road.

@TimSeifert : As you point out, this is equivalent to shifting the binary representation of the chosen real number. This is known as the Bernoulli shift. For almost all real numbers, the orbit is dense; this is a rephrasing of Borel’s theorem that almost all numbers are normal (that is, the set of numbers such that any finite-length string of bits can be found -with the right density- in their binary expansion has full measure).

@JohnBollinger If the track length is irrational, choose a rational step size. It's just a convenient way of avoiding picking a step size that could evenly divide the track. Between the track size and step size, it doesn't really matter which is rational for this answer, so long as one is and one isn't.

@Vincent True, just picking random step sizes will also work almost surely in the long term with 100% probability. I suppose a random strategy still might be "worse" than the solution here, though - no matter how long we check random segments, there's a chance we still haven't found the exit. Deterministic strategies with better "coverage" (not sure of the proper term, or if this answer is actually an example of one) will have a constantly decreasing largest unchecked segment size, guaranteeing that an exit of non-zero size will be found after a finite number of steps.


 Assume without loss of generality that the circle has circumference $1$, and the points are identified with their clockwise distance from your starting point. For example, your starting point is $0$, a quarter around the track clockwise is $\frac{1}{4}$, a quarter in the other direction is $\frac{3}{4}$, and so on. For simplicity all numbers are taken modulo $1$, so $\frac{3}{4}$ may also be called $-\frac{1}{4}$, or $42 + \frac{3}{4}$.


 Given any positive integer $n$ and some starting point $p$, we can visit all points at locations $p + \frac{k}{2^n}$ for any $k$ with $0 \leq k < 2^n$, ending up at one of the points (we won't necessarily know which), as follows.


 If $n = 1$, travel half the circumference. It doesn't matter which direction you go; you reach $p + \frac{1}{2}$ either way.


 If $n > 1$, apply the procedure for $n - 1$. You have now reached all points $p + \frac{2k}{2^n}$ for all $k$ with $0 \leq k < 2^{n-1}$, and you are at some point $p + \frac{2k'}{2^n}$ for some $k'$ with $0 \leq k' < 2^{n-1}$. You do not necessarily know the value of $k'$. Travel distance $\frac{1}{2^n}$ in an arbitrary direction. You are now some point $p'$ which is at either $p + \frac{2k' + 1}{2^n}$ or $p + \frac{2k' - 1}{2^n}$. Perform the procedure for $n-1$ again, starting at $p'$. The idea is you've already seen all the even-valued points spaced $\frac{1}{2^n}$ around the circle (from $p$), and now you're visiting the odd-numbered ones, thus completing the procedure for $n$.


 Now $n$ may be taken arbitrarily high, allowing you to inspect all intervals of any arbitrarily small length.


This seems to be identical to the answer by fljx.
